# О выводе графики

Tags: java, android, canvas, opengl, графика

Нужна помощь в структуризации моих знаний о том как выводится графики и проблема эта появилась в момент когда я писал простенькую игрушку и делал её частями, совсем не подумав об архитектуре ибо думать о ней не мог, так как учусь и не знал что вообще придется применять.

В одном классе у меня графика выводится с помощью методов движка `AndEngine`, в другой всё используется `Layout` для создания поля и фигуры на нём вывожу с помощью `Canvas`.

В `Layout` было легко задать поле, подключил библиотеку:

```
'com.android.support:percent:24.2.1'
```

и вообще все поля можно задавать в процентных соотношениях и стало проблемой как же теперь переписать всё.

И чтобы начать это делать хочу понять чем вообще принципиальное отличие этих способов вывода графики. (Да знаю это не способы вывода графики. Способы это `Canvas` или `OpenGL`). В общем я запутался.

Есть еще `GraphicsView`, это обертка над чем? и зачем этот класс создали? когда писать в лояуте, когда  лучше с помощью `GraphicsView`? Про `OpenGL` вообще молчу, я наверно ни под какими обертками с ним не сталкивался, хотя может `AndEngine` как раз его и использует?